# Can't change "Postcode / ZIP" field label in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a site in hebrew based on woocommerce. The translation working great, however, the field "Postcode / ZIP" is refuse to be trasnlate:

[image]

I've tried to change it using this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['label'] = 'test';

    return $fields;
}
```

But something weird happen: when I reload the page I can see the change take effect, but after a second it change back to "Postcode / ZIP".
Another weird thing: the above script work for the other fields, something is wrong with that specific field.

Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: If the value is changing after page load it could possibiliy be becuase of some javascript function. Check if you have created any function which might be affecting the label. With the same you (where have tried to change the label to 'test'), try to keep it blank `$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['label'] = 'test';` and then see of the label text "Postcode / ZIP" auto populates.

Comment: @zipkundan no it's not auto populates when I leave it blank.. Whoo is the immediate suspect? javascript?

Comment: Well, if it is not auto populating after leaing it blank, then I guess javascript is not manipulating it. I would suggest to check if you have enabled `gettext` filter in your theme's function file. Probably that might be causing it.

Comment: @zipkundan Thanks man! using `get_text` filter solve the problem

Comment: Glad it is solved :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Postcode / ZIP' :
            $translated_text = __( 'test', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: It works for sure, try debug it and see if the filter is being execute

Comment: how to execute debug mode? please leave me a link